# How do I pass in parameters to the express.js server side routing for a MEAN.js package.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, angular-ui-router

I am a beginner working on a project structured by mean.js. I am still trying to figure out how the whole project struct works and I am a little stuck.

Currently, I have two crud modules. A project module and an application module. Users should be able to apply to projects. Under a certain project, I should be able to view all the applications and then accept/reject them.

I added a custom method onto the angular $resource

```
function ProjectApplicationsService($resource) {
    return $resource('api/projects/:projectId/applications', { projectId: '@_id' }, {
      accept: {
        method: 'PUT'
      },
      reject: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });

  }
```

Once I click a button corresponding to a certain application, it will trigger this function and pass in the application ID as a parameter.

```
function acceptApp(applicationID){
      vm.application._id = vm.project._id;
      vm.application.app_id = applicationID;
      vm.application.$accept(successCallback, errorCallback);
      function successCallback(res) {
          console.log("success");
      }

      function errorCallback(res) {
        vm.error = res.data.message;
        console.log(vm.error);
      }
    }
```

This should make an API call to express and here is the routing for that

```
  app.route('/api/projects/:projectId/applications')
    .get(users.requiresLogin, projects.hasAuthorization, projects.getApplications)
    .put(users.requiresLogin, projects.hasAuthorization, projects.updateApplication)
    .delete(users.requiresLogin, projects.hasAuthorization, projects.deleteApplication);
```

Essentially, I want to end up calling updateApplication but how do I get the application ID within this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're going to upload something to the server which will trigger your `put` route - which contains the function you want to call.

You need to structure your handles like so:

```
function(request,response,next){ // usually abbreviated to `req,res`
    handleData();
    next(); // move onto the next function;
}
```

The parameters are easy to remember by, request comes before response, and then next - You only need next when you want to move onto another handler.

If you don't call `next()` the route will stop - you'll probably want to call next once authorization succeeds.

data is held in the requests body, so you can access it using `request.body`

Note: remember to respond to your user - with something like `res.send("success")`, or they'll time out

Comment: Man I literally just figured this out. Request.body was the key. Thanks!!